# Lombok @delegate annotation not passing values to innerDTO

Tags: java, delegates, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

inside my test class

```
String json="{\n" +
                "\t\"masterName\": \"test1\",\n" +
                "\t\"masterSubjectName\": \"testsubject\",\n" +
                "\t\"masterRoll\": \"534\",\n" +
                "\t\"firstName\": \"studentFirstName\",\n" +
                "\t\"rollNumber\": \"23\"\n" +
                "}";
        
        Student studentDTO=new Gson().fromJson(json, Student.class);
        System.out.println(studentDTO);
```

Student.java

```
@Data
public class Student {
    

    @Delegate(types = Master.class)
    private Master master=new Master();

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int rollNumber;
}
```

Master.java

```
@Data
public class Master {

    private String masterName;
    private String masterSubjectName;
    private int masterRoll;
}
```

This gives Response:

```
Student(master=Master(masterName=null, masterSubjectName=null, masterRoll=0), firstName=studentFirstName, lastName=null, rollNumber=23)
```

When I parse the json string "json" to the Student class,

1. Why values not getting passed to "Master.java" inner dto?
2. I need something like Student(masterName=test1, masterSubjectName=testsubject, masterRoll=534, firstName=studentFirstName,rollNumber=23)

Answer (score 1):

Your 'types' value in @Delegate should be Interface with getter methods for example getMasterName() , getMasterSubjectName... and so on

documentation:
https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate